# After the image has been saved, can I still edit text-boxes & shapes in Preview.app?

Tags: macos, preview, image-editing

If I add text boxes and shapes to an image using Preview.app, save that image, and then close the image window, the next time that I open the image in Preview, all additions are uneditable.

In other words, all edits are made permanent upon save.

Is there a way to retain the ability to modify markup elements in Preview.app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the edits are saved directly to the image.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert the image to a PDF, and then edit the PDF, you can edit the additions in Preview.app, even after saving.

To save an image as a PDF, you can use:

- *File* → *Export As PDF...*
- *File* → *Export...*
- *File* → *Print* → *PDF* → *Save As PDF...*